# How to show that if $U$ is an open set in a product topology then $\pi_{i}(U)=E_i$ for all but finitely many indices $I.$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

**Problem Statement:**

Let $((E_i,T_i))_{i\in I}$ be a family of non-empty topological spaces. If $U$ is any $\Pi_{i\in I} T_i$-open subset of $\Pi_{i\in I}E_{i}$ prove that $\pi_{i}(U)=E_i$ for all but finitely many indices $i$ in $I$, where $\pi_i$ is the projection mapping from $E$ to $E_i.$

**My Attempt:**

If $U$ is any open set in the product topology then we have that 
$$U=\bigcup_{k\in K}\prod_{i\in I}U_{ik}$$
where $U_{ik}\in T_{i}.$ Thus 
$$\pi_{i}(U)=\pi_{i}\left(\bigcup_{k\in K}\prod_{j\in I}U_{jk}\right)$$
$$=\bigcup_{k\in K}\pi_{i}\left(\prod_{j\in I}U_{jk}\right)=\bigcup_{k\in K}U_{ik}.$$
How do I proceed after this step?

Comment: I don't understand "If $U$ is any open set in any $\Pi_{i\in I} T_i$-open subset of $\Pi_{i\in I}E_{i}$"...

Comment: @amsmath I made an edit. Please read the problem again.

Comment: What  if $U = \prod_{i\in I}U_i$? Then $\pi_i(U) = U_i$. So the claim is false.

Comment: @amsmath Unless $I$ is finite, the set $U$ is not open in the product topology.

Comment: @Paul Frost I did not read the Wikipedia definition well enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but you forgot that for each basic open $B = \Pi_{i \in I} U_i$ you have $U_i = E_i$ for all but finitely many $i$. This means that $\pi_i(B) = E_i$ for all but finitely many $i$. Therefore, if $B \subset M$, then $\pi_i(M) = E_i$ for all but finitely many $i$.

Comment: @Hello_World If the answer is okay, you should officially accept it. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers .

Comment: Where does B come in the proof?